# Need help identifying antique porcelain fuse block

Tags: power-supply, identification, fuses, vintage, fuse-holders

This is an antique 30 amp porcelain fuse block from a house, built before electricity, that was first wired around 1900. I would like to identify the manufacturer and the year of manufacture of this fuse holder. The reason I removed this from the house is because I am trying to identify the exact year this house was first wired and I had read somewhere that some of these fuse blocks have the year of manufacture written on them, but this one doesn't. If I'm not mistaken, most home electrical systems were 60 amps at this time, and so I assume there was (or still is) another one of these somewhere else in the house (it was located about 15 feet from where the power appears to have come in, but didn't appear to have any wires above 14 AWG connected to it). I assume that number on the back is a serial number. [image][image][image][image][image][image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this site is for questions about electrical engineering theory and design.

Comment: We do allow component identification questions sometimes, but usually electronics components rather than distribution parts.  DIY stack exchange has more electricians and less engineers, which could improve your chances if the question is allowed, but you might want to consider r/whatisthisthing/ on reddit.  They're more frendly to this kind of obsolete obscurity as their focus is on pure identification whereas here it's usually identification for the purpose of functional replacement, which is different.

Comment: I thought this question was okay because I saw a similar question here.

Comment: @Sagierian You have to @ people at the start of your comment if you want them to notice you replied.  Only the writer of a question or answer gets automatic notification.  If you click "Tour" under "Electrical Engineering" at the bottom left of the page you'll find the bulk of the site rules and [click here](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6710/component-identification-question-guidelines) to read the meta for guidelines on acceptable component identification questions.  Read the question and all answers as it is *people discussing potential rules* not necessarily rules.

Comment: A similar GE cat. No. 62965 dual fuse holder is currently listed on eBay with a patent date of 1901. Yours could be a knock-off, earlier model or whatever.. and of course patent date does not tell you the manufacture date,